# Particles do not appear on the particles div

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I'm trying to use particles.js as a background for a website. Currently, the particles div is present, but the particles do not appear. How could i fix this?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./particles.js-master/demo/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./particles.js-master/particles.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body {
    background: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

#particles-js {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I know that particles-js is present because changing its background color makes an affect on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the particles js config as well for it to work. You can create and download the json config from https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 particlesJS("particles-js",<strong>Your JSON here</strong>);
</script>
```

For example my json might look like:

```
 {
 "particles": {
 "number": {
 "value": 80,
 "density": {
 "enable": true,
 "value_area": 800
 }
 },
 "color": {
 "value": "#ffffff"
 },
 "shape": {
 "type": "circle",
 "stroke": {
 "width": 0,
 "color": "#000000"
 },
 "polygon": {
 "nb_sides": 5
 },
 "image": {
 "src": "img/github.svg",
 "width": 100,
 "height": 100
 }
 },
 "opacity": {
 "value": 0.5,
 "random": false,
 "anim": {
 "enable": false,
 "speed": 1,
 "opacity_min": 0.1,
 "sync": false
 }
 },
 "size": {
 "value": 3,
 "random": true,
 "anim": {
 "enable": false,
 "speed": 40,
 "size_min": 0.1,
 "sync": false
 }
 },
 "line_linked": {
 "enable": true,
 "distance": 150,
 "color": "#ffffff",
 "opacity": 0.4,
 "width": 1
 },
 "move": {
 "enable": true,
 "speed": 6,
 "direction": "none",
 "random": false,
 "straight": false,
 "out_mode": "out",
 "bounce": false,
 "attract": {
 "enable": false,
 "rotateX": 600,
 "rotateY": 1200
 }
 }
 },
 "interactivity": {
 "detect_on": "canvas",
 "events": {
 "onhover": {
 "enable": true,
 "mode": "repulse"
 },
 "onclick": {
 "enable": true,
 "mode": "push"
 },
 "resize": true
 },
 "modes": {
 "grab": {
 "distance": 400,
 "line_linked": {
 "opacity": 1
 }
 },
 "bubble": {
 "distance": 400,
 "size": 40,
 "duration": 2,
 "opacity": 8,
 "speed": 3
 },
 "repulse": {
 "distance": 200,
 "duration": 0.4
 },
 "push": {
 "particles_nb": 4
 },
 "remove": {
 "particles_nb": 2
 }
 }
 },
 "retina_detect": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* ---- particles.js config ---- */

particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 380,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});


/* ---- stats.js config ---- */

var count_particles, stats, update;
stats = new Stats;
stats.setMode(0);
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
count_particles = document.querySelector('.particles-js');
update = function() {
  stats.begin();
  stats.end();
  if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
    count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for your detailed responses. But in case anyone ever sees this problem again, the problem was that my adblocker was not allowing the particles javascript.